# File Storage for Web Applications during production

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, flask, filesystems

Which form of file system SQL, NoSQL, the cloud, or a static/subdirectory inside the application should I use for my web application?

sql: I've tried to save the images as blobs, but I can't get them out and display them on the flask application.

Cloud storage: I successfully built an S3 bucket, placed a file there, and am now able to view website images. I attempted to deploy the website on ec2, with the aws id and secret key properly specified in the configure file. My s3 bucket is public, however my nginx server reports a "502 bad gateway" (in localhost it works fine).

File system: Storing an application's images within a folder and its metadata in a mysql database. This method functions without any problems, but the question is whether it will result in more photographs being kept in the folder as the application ages, say, if I want to keep the images for a longer period of time.

1. Does it cause a server stess?
2. Is this way of saving the images effectively?
3. Does it slow down the application process over time as no of images increases?
4. What additional issues can I encounter as a result of this process?

Comment: removed [tag:random] as I don't see how it applies here.  you seem to be asking a lot of questions without providing much in the way of detail that would be needed to answer them.  e.g. how are you defining "server stress"? do you consider AWS S3 servers in this "stress", what usage/traffic patterns are you expecting? I'd suggest benchmarking your use case if this is new, and read around the many documents already written

Comment: What I really intended to ask was should I use an S3 bucket or a static folder to keep the images, if I maintain a folder to preserve them? Does the size of the folder affect the performance of the website?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76305893/when-storing-an-image-in-an-s3-bucket-nginx-displays-a-502-bad-gateway-error this is error i am getting with s3 bucket in production server.

Comment: how many images? what size? how many users? what duration? are they static images, or are they submitted by users?  I'd generally go with the local filesystem as it's quick and easy.  S3 has use cases, but if you're getting started it's just more complication to worry about

Comment: let's say max images is 1000, of size less than 1 mb, duration is not more than 2 months and yes they are submitted by users.

Comment: with that volume it isn't going to matter what you do, just do whatever is easiest.  if you're expecting 1000 new images a day then you can start thinking about what you're doing, at a million a day you need to be careful