# When storing an image in an S3 bucket, nginx displays a 502 Bad Gateway error

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, amazon-s3

I can store images in a bucket on a local host and retrieve them.

1. the bucket is open to the public.
2. The secret key and access ID for AWS are correctly configured.
   Ngnix serves bad gateway errors and the exception error "unable to locate credentials" when in production

Nginx config file :

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name 44.202.12.251;

        location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/Project/Project/project/static;
}

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
}

}
```

Bucket Policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::flasklara/*"
        }
    ]
}
```